# In vite + vue3 + TS project, AWS Amplify Failed to resolve components

Tags: javascript, aws-amplify, vuejs3, vite, aws-amplify-vue

I am having hard time to make AWS Amplify work with [Vite.js](https://vitejs.dev/)

```
// First I was getting this error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
```

So, I added this `script` in index.html's `head` section

```
<script>
  var global = global || window;
  var Buffer = Buffer || [];
  var process = process || {
    env: { DEBUG: undefined },
    version: []
  };
</script>
```

Now, I am getting this warning/error

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: amplify-sign-out 
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: amplify-authenticator
```

You can see complete logs here:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix the resolve component errors by creating a **vue.config.js** file in the app root directory and adding the following:

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('vue')
      .use('vue-loader')
      .tap(options => {
        options.compilerOptions = {
          ...(options.compilerOptions || {}),
          isCustomElement: tag => tag.startsWith('amplify-')
        };
        return options;
      });
  }
};
```

Comment: This worked, thanks for that. Just a note for anyone else, I had to restart the app for it to take effect.

Comment: This gets rid of the errors for me, but the authenticator is not working. I'm expecting it to popup when the page is loaded, but I'm just getting my page with its content.

Answer (score -1):

According to [AWS Amplify doc](https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/auth/authenticator/q/framework/vue#usage), you need to add `app.config.isCustomElement = tag => tag.startsWith('amplify-');` to your `main.ts` file.

Since you're using vite, you can also do so by following the [vite example](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/tree/main/packages/plugin-vue#example-for-passing-options-to-vuecompiler-dom). The `vite.config.ts` file should be like

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue({
      template: {
        compilerOptions: {
          isCustomElement: (tag) => tag.startsWith("amplify-"),
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
});
```